# Custom IntelliJ Idea Shortcuts - Plugin or Keymap?

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea

I want to create a shortcut similar to Ctrl+Shift+T in Idea. Instead of switching between Class and Test, i want to switch between XModel, XView and XController based on the current tab (X). Should i create a plugin or is this achievable in Keymap?

Comment: Did you finally find an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware (as of IDEA 10), this would require a plugin where you'd configure the file extensions that were grouped together.